# Como pôr ícone do lado do texto?

Tags: css, html5

Galera, estou tentando pôr uma imagem/ícone do lado de uma frase, só que a imagem sobe, fica em cima. Como resolvo isso?

Ex: (ícone) Fale Conosco

Comment: Bruno coloque o código que já desenvolveu. Para saber como fazer perguntas no site de uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: a tag <img> é uma tag inline, texto também.
Se fizer isso:
<p><img src="..." /> Olá</p>
Tem que ficar do lado.

Acredito que tu esteja fazendo assim:
<img src="..."><p>Olá</p>
Desse jeito vai cair, porque <p> é uma tag de bloco.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você inserir no html a imagem dentro do paragrafo `<p><img></p>`, e ajustar o tamanho da imagem:

```css
img{
width:15px;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/59/59965.svg"> Fale Conosco </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

é sempre uma boa prática utilizar flexbox:

```css
.mycontainer{
display: flex;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">

<span>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" alt="">
</span>
<span>
lorem ipsum
</span>
</div>
```

Segue um link com ótimo conteúdo sobre a prática de flexbox, ajuda muito no dia-a-dia:
[flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)